# Get only first row from join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a special behavior on a mysql request.

Here are my tables :

```
users
id, email

infos_users
id_user, firstName, lastName, avatar

chatroom
id

chatroomUsers
id_chatroom, id_user

chatMessage
id, id_chatroom, message, id_sender
```

The thing i want to do is to get every room with its users based on a user id, to get every chatroom the user is in. To do this, i'm using this request :

```
SELECT     chatroomUsers.id_chatroom, 
           users.id, 
           infos_user.avatar, 
           infos_user.firstName, 
           infos_user.lastName  
FROM       chatroomUsers 
INNER JOIN users      ON chatroomUsers.id_user = users.id 
INNER JOIN infos_user ON infos_user.id_user = users.id 
WHERE      id_chatroom IN 
(
    SELECT id_chatroom 
    FROM   chatroomUsers 
    WHERE  id_user = ?
)
```

Where `?` is the id of the user i'm focusing on. Of course, i'm doing some post processing to clean everything and to have a nice array with key = id_chatroom and value an array of users.

So what's next ? Well i want for every row, the last message of the chatroom (which is the one with the corresponding id_chatroom and the highest id_message value). Currently the request returns me this:

```
id_chatroom     id   avatar      firstName  lastName
0               0    avatar1     blah1      blah2
0               1    avatar2     blah3      blah4
1               2    avatar3     blah5      blah6
1               1    avatar1     blah1      blah2
1               3    avatar4     blah7      blah8
```

And i want something like this :

```
id_chatroom     id   avatar      firstName  lastName    lastMessage         id_message  id_sender
0               0    avatar1     blah1      blah2       blahblahblah        0           1
0               1    avatar2     blah3      blah4       blahblahblah        0           1
1               2    avatar3     blah5      blah6       blahblahblahblah    1           3
1               1    avatar1     blah1      blah2       blahblahblahblah    1           3
1               3    avatar4     blah7      blah8       blahblahblahblah    1           3
```

Once again, in order to do some post processing. But every time i try to construct my request, it messes up everything.

Can someone help me?

EDIT : There could be no messages recorded for the chatroom ! In that case, i want messages fields to be filled with `null`.

Comment: can you explain what you want didn't understand what you asked what the querry should returns ?

Comment: @Charif Is it unclear ? Everything is in the post !

Comment: i didnt understand this 
 in the result the  "id" is the id of the chatroom or the user  because in the end there is sender_id

Comment: the id is the id of the user in the chatroom. the id_sender is the id of the user that posted the last message on the chatroom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want last message of one chat room, you should use a sub query; if you want to fill message columns which has no message per chat room with `null` value, you have to use `left join`, so we can do it like this(maybe a quite simple one):

```
SELECT     chatroomUsers.id_chatroom, 
           users.id, 
           infos_user.avatar, 
           infos_user.firstName, 
           infos_user.lastName,
           sub.message AS lastMessage,
           sub.id AS id_message,
           sub.id_sender
FROM       chatroomUsers 
INNER JOIN users      ON chatroomUsers.id_user = users.id 
INNER JOIN infos_user ON infos_user.id_user = users.id
LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM chatMessage t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(id) AS id, id_chatroom
        FROM chatMessage
        GROUP BY id_chatroom
    ) t2 ON t1.id_chatroom = t2.id_chatroom AND t1.id = t2.id
) sub                  ON chatroomUsers.id_chatroom = sub.id_chatroom 
WHERE      id_chatroom IN 
(
    SELECT id_chatroom 
    FROM   chatroomUsers 
    WHERE  id_user = ?
)
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   cru.id_chatroom, 
   u.id, 
   iu.avatar, 
   iu.firstName, 
   iu.lastName,
   cm.message AS lastMessage,
   xx.max_id AS id_message,
   cm.id_sender
FROM chatroomUsers cru
JOIN users u ON cru.id_user = u.id 
JOIN infos_user iu ON iu.id_user = u.id 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        MAX(cmx.id) AS max_id,
        cmx.id_chatroom
    FROM chatroomUsers cmx
    GROUP BY id_chatroom
) xx ON xx.id_chatroom = cru.id_chatroom
LEFT JOIN chatroomUsers cm ON (cm.id = xx.id)
WHERE      id_chatroom IN 
(chatroomUsers
    SELECT id_chatroom 
    FROM   chatroomUsers 
    WHERE  id_user = ?
);
```

Here, you're joining on a subselect that has the last ID (`MAX(id)`) for every chatroom. Then you're joining again to get the contents of that message.

I used left joins, since I wasn't sure of your data model. I *think* a user could be in a room, but the room could be brand new, with nothing said yet. The left join makes sure you can show the rest of the user info in that case.

---

*Caveat lector: I don't have MySQL handy to test this out.*

Comment: Ok, i tried it and it was full of errors i had to fix. But still doesn't work... A room cannot be brand new. It has to have at least two users in. And something i haven't said in the first post, but it could have no messages in. In that case, i want that all of the fields related to the messages to be filled with null.

Comment: Ah, I left a group by id_sender in that should be taken out. I'll edit, although you already have your answer, which basically does the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use some kind of datestamp column for this, but you can do it with the autoincrementing IDs.

```
(SELECT id_chatroom, message FROM chatMessage INNER JOIN (SELECT id_chatroom, max(id) AS most_recent_id FROM chatMessage GROUP BY id_chatroom) mostRecents ON chatMessage.id = mostRecents.most_recent_id)
```

If you throw that constructed table into your joins, it should work. This kind of stuff always feels gross but I've never found a better way to ORDER and *then* GROUP.

Comment: I have some kind of datestamp, but not usable by mysql (only for post processing). I think this is doable with the highest id only.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the SELECT TOP Clause.

So

```
SELECT TOP 1  chatroomUsers.id_chatroom, 
       users.id, 
       infos_user.avatar, 
       infos_user.firstName, 
       infos_user.lastName
```